# Warning when presenting a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am creating another instance my main view controller and presenting it.

```
MainViewController *sm = [[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:sm animated:NO];
[sm release];
```

This gives the following errors

> warning: receiver 'MainViewController' is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist
>
> warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct MainViewController *', expected 'struct UIViewController *' when passing argument 1 of 'presentModalViewController:animated:' from distinct Objective-C type

What am I doing wrong? How can I present the current version of MainViewController that exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a forward declaration in your header file

```
@class MainViewController;
```

but you do not import the header file in your implementation file.

Add

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
```

to the top of the .m file.

Answer (score 0):

## import "MainViewController.h"

in your .m file.